# The song title is overlapping the picker title while selecting a song using MPMediaPickerController from a Genius playlist

Tags: iphone, ios, playlist, mpmediapickercontroller

I am using a

`MPMediaPickerController`

to pick songs to add to a playlist in my app. using the following code,
for selecting a song from a Genius playlist the song title is overlapping the picker title as shown in the image1. for any other case the text is not overlapping.
can someone please help me how to fix that.

```
- (void)addToPlaylist: (id)sender {
MPMediaPickerController* picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyVideo]; 

picker.delegate = self; 
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES; 
picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsToPlaylist", nil);

[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES]; 
[picker release];
}
```

-----------------image 1------------------------------ normal song selection

[image: genius playlist overlapping title]    [image: normal selection of image] [image]